# How can I embed an image in an Apple Mail signature?

Tags: snow-leopard, mail.app, signature, formatting

I use Apple Mail daily, and up until recently I could have images inside my mail by referencing an external source. However the external source has since become unavailable, so ideally I would like to embed the images into my mail signatures. I am pretty good with creating the signature in HTML and create the webarchive for it, however have no idea where to begin as far as embedding the images are concerned.

Has anyone actually done this, or know of a very good resource that I can use to figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Once the Mail program has launched, open the Mail application Preferences. This can be done by selecting it from the Mail menu bar option or by using the "Command - ," keyboard shortcut, which simply consists of pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> at the same time.
2. Choose the "Signatures" option of the Mail Preferences window.
3. Add a new signature profile by clicking on the "Create a Signature" button located under the second pane within the Signatures Preferences window. This button is represented by a square containing a plus (+) sign. See accompanying image.
4. In the third pane located within the Mail Signatures Preferences Window, type the text of your email signature. You can also paste your text from another application, like Microsoft Word, Apple Pages or Apple TextEdit. Pasting from another application will maintain the text's font, size and style, if that is something you need or desire. Keep in mind that some fonts may not display properly on the email recipient's computer, depending upon the fonts you use and the fonts they have.
5. ***Assuming that you have an image that you wish to add to your new signature, just drag the image from its location on your Mac (using the Finder) and drop it in the same pane where you just typed or pasted your new signature text. The image should appear next to or below your text. Make sure to use only web compatible images - JPG, PNG or GIF.***

Comment: You should have mentioned that this answer was copied & pasted [from eHow.com](http://www.ehow.com/how_4698848_image-email-signature-apple-mail.html).

Comment: 4. doesn't seem to work when copy/pasting images from Thunderbird to Mail. Strangely, when I compose an email in Mail, the image shows when I write the mail, but when receiving the mail, the image doesn't show. I am copy/pasting html code from Thunderbird (but from rendered view) where the images are referenced like <a href="file:///Users/myuser/myimage.jpg">, however, when looking into the raw source of the received mail I see that the reference in html still remains like that, and the images have not been embedded into the mail.

Comment: For anyone who hits this, Apple's email doesn't embed local images. You'll see them when you're writing but they won't arrive at the other end. Safari's web archive has the same issue. In both cases, what's "embedded" is a link to the image. Not very useful if (1) the image is on your local machine or (2) the website disappears. The later happens all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply drag an image file into a signature in Mail.

This will embed the image with in the email so all your future emails will include an attachment.

I sugest using a PNG as they are quite light-weight.

Comment: Dragging a image file in Apple Mail (signatures) will treat it as attachment - I wouldn't call this "embedded"...